Order of convergence $p$ of steepest descent for $f=5x^2+5y^2-xy-11x+11y+11$
I found a similar post, however I don't understand the answer. I want to find it by definition $\overline{\lim_{k\to\infty}}\frac{\|\mathbf{x}_{k+1}-\mathbf{x}^*\|}{\|\mathbf{x}_{k}-\mathbf{x}^*\|^p}=\beta$.
$\mathbf{x}^*=(1,-1)^T,\mathbf{x}_{k+1}=\mathbf{x}_k-\alpha_k\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_k)$ where $\alpha_k$ is solution to $\min f(\mathbf{x}_k-\alpha_k\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_k))$ subject to $\alpha_k\geq0$.
$$\begin{align*}
\nabla f&=(10x-y-11,10y-x+11)^T\\
g(\alpha)&=f(x_k-\alpha(10x_k-y_k-11),y_k-\alpha(10y_k-x_k+11))\\
g'&=(10(x_k-\alpha(10x_k-y_k-11)-(y_k-\alpha(10y_k-x_k+11))-11)(-10x_k+y_k+11)+(-(x_k-\alpha(10x_k-y_k-11)+10(y_k-\alpha(10y_k-x_k+11))+11)(-10y_k+x_k-11)
\end{align*}$$
However solving $g'=0$ for $\alpha$ is tedious. Is my direction correct?
Thanks!
